# After upgrading from .NET Core 2.1 to 3.1 Views aren't being found when my app starts in E2E tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In `Home` controller I'm returning `return View("Login", ReturnUrl);`

In `Views/Home/` there's `Login.cshtml`

**Everything works fine when I manually start the app**, but when I'm starting application in Selenium tests like that:

```
[Parallelizable]
[Test]
public async Task TEST()
{
    var info = this.ConnectionInfo[Configure()];
    foreach (var driver in GetDrivers())
    {
        var _context = GetDb(info.ConnectionString);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

        _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(info.Address);
    }
}

public Guid Configure()
{
    var addressId = Guid.NewGuid();
    
    var port1 = FreeTcpPort();
    var port2 = FreeTcpPort();

    var dbFileGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".db";

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();

    config["Tests:ConnectionString"] = $"Filename={dbFileGuid}";

    _host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseConfiguration
                (
                    config
                )
                .UseUrls($"http://localhost:{port1}/", $"https://localhost:{port2}/")
                .UseStartup<TestsStartup>()
                .UseSerilog()
                .Build();

    _host.StartAsync();

    ConnectionInfo.TryAdd(addressId, new ConnectionInfo($"http://127.0.0.1:{port1}", dbFileGuid, _host));

    return addressId;
}
```

`TestStartup` is using the same methods to configure `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` as my real config, with the difference in `DatabaseContext` provider.

Here's what appears during tests

[image]

Here are my parts of Startup

```
services
    .AddControllersWithViews(x =>
    {
        x.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilter));
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson()
    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(HomeController).Assembly)
    .AddControllersAsServices()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

services
    .AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();



app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute
    (
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

What may cause that App is unable to find those Views when started from Tests meanwhile it managed to do it on older .NET Core / older ASP libs?

Comment: You can change the view property (Build Action, Copy to output directory). This will probably fix your issue, screen is attached here: https://i.ibb.co/fvWFBsr/Embedded-Resource.png

Answer (score 3):

Well,

I managed to fix it in kinda hackly by telling `Test` project to copy `Views` folder from the app folder to `Test's bin`

That's what I added to the `.csproj`

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\MyApp\Views\**" Link="Views\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change two things in the startup file:
(Add MVC to your project pipeline)

```
services
    .AddControllersWithViews(x =>
    {
        x.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilter));
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson()
    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(HomeController).Assembly)
    .AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

Then change your endpoint like this: (it's default routing for MVC project)

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});
```